# Illustrator - set stroke colour of multiple objects as respective fill colours

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, stroke

I have traced a photo in Illustrator, resulting in a complicated vector image with 20 colours.

I would like to add a stroke to all of the shapes in the image and set the stroke colour to be the same as the fill colour of each individual shape, e.g. shapes filled red will have a red stroke and shape filled blue will have a blue stroke.

Is there an option which does this automatically, or will I have to set the stroke colour of each shape individually?

Comment: Was there ever any answer to this - it seems like something that the program should do automatically.

Comment: Relevant (or duplicate) http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41767/automatically-make-various-multiple-stroke-colour-the-same-as-various-underlying

Comment: Thanks @Scott - definitely relevant. Hadn't considered a custom script.

Comment: Is there any better solution to this than a custom script? Is Illustrator stuck in the 80' in this regard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort of do this in Illustrator by expanding the paths themselves, instead of using a stroke.

1. Select all objects and set their strokes to none
2. Use the menu command Object → Path → Offset Path…
3. Use the Offset amount to increase the width of your shape while retaining the fill color

*For more information watch: [http://youtu.be/lS1HDKRGVe0](http://youtu.be/lS1HDKRGVe0_)*

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution, but a workaround: you can use the Magic Wand tool to select all shapes that have identical (or very similar, depending on your settings) fill colour, all at once. When they are selected, you can give them all the same fill colour.

You'll still have to repeat the process for each colour, but 40 clicks (two for each colour) still better than a few hundred...