# Low Poly Problem in Illustrator - White Lines Around Shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, stroke, fill

I made this Low poly image (zoomed in version of just the eye).  I followed all of the steps and I couldn't have done anything wrong:

[image: current]

If you look closely, you can see these white lines between every shape

When you zoom out, the whole image looks like that; full of white lines and very unprofessional.

What I can do is change the stroke of every single object to its fill color, but that'd take me hours (I have about a couple thousand shapes in this image alone).

Is there a way to select all of the objects on a layer in and choose "Make Stroke color same as Fill color" or something of the sort?

This is what I want the finished product to look like (note: there are no more white lines):

[image: desired]

I achieved this look by *leaving* the tracing image in the background so that it sort of fills in the white lines

Comment: This is a bug in the rendering engine called a conflation artefact, this is explained for example [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg/65060#65060). Even if you do a perfect job it still happens because there is a fundamental flaw in the rendering engine. If you export the image with art optimized then these are not visible. You can over underlap the triangles if you want to fix this but thats a lot of work (see [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/space-between-2-paths-illustrator/47345#47345))

Comment: This is also not just Illustrators fault, its actually more prominent on many other vector egines.

Comment: It does not matter if the shapes do not overlap then even if you have a mathematically perfect join it will bug out. When you conflate trandsparency and coverage lke 99% of all vector engines do because 50% transparency on 50% is 75% not a hundred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another similar post here on *Stack Exchange* which pretty much solves the problem...

---

### "Set stroke color of multiple objects as respective fill colors".

-You can sort of do this in Illustrator by expanding the paths themselves, instead of using a stroke.

1. Select all objects and set their strokes to none
2. Use the menu command Object → Path → Offset Path…
3. Use the Offset amount to increase the width of your shape while retaining the fill color

For more information watch: http://youtu.be/lS1HDKRGVe0

[Link Here](http://www.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39489/illustrator-set-stroke-colour-of-multiple-objects-as-respective-fill-colours)