# White lines when I'm coloring a shape with darker colors in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm quite new with Illustrator and I have an issue that I'm trying to find a soluting for a few hours now!

So when I use dark colors on any shape a white thin line appears around it. I tried adding a stroke but the white line moves around the stroke.
This is only happening when I'm using dark colors, the lighter colors look as they should!
I tried to export as a .png & .pdf and the lines are still visible.

Without a stroke:

[image]

With a stroke:

[image]

Random light colors:

[image]

(Edit)
I didn't convert any image to make my design.I drew it right from the start.
I tried it again without using divide on my shapes, it still looks the same.
I tried to add Offset paths,nothing changed.Even if I add a background the lines are still showing!

English is not my first language, I hope I was understood!

Comment: Also possible duplicate https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/71234/63979

Comment: @WELZ I tried everything that was suggested in those two posts you linked but unfortunately nothing worked. The issue for me is only when I'm coloring with dark colors.

Comment: Have you tried *exporting* your artwork? It is usually only visible while it's still vector.

Comment: I tried exporting as .pdf, .png, .jpg, .svg and it looks even worse

Comment: The lines still look like [conflation artifacts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/65060/41100) to me. The lighter color however I cannot explain. Looks like an issue with your GPU. Try disabling GPU accelleration and see if that fixes it, else try updating your drivers (there was a [known issue with NVIDIA cards](https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/601447-illustrator-bugs/category/209149-gpu-rendering-issues) not too long ago)

Answer (score 0):

Check under the View menu to see if you have Pixel Preview turned on, it could cause issues like you are describing.